# sed c command with full capture group

Tags: linux, bash, sed, scripting

I have read through dozens of sed questions, none of them are related to what I'm trying to do. I am using the sed `c` command to match multiple lines within a file, but I need the contents between the two sections.

```
a
begin
c

d

end
f
...
```

I need to capture the 2 lines `c` and `d` in this example and remove the new lines between, and use them in the output, but nothing I have tried or can find allows me to capture from the match expression.

With some pseudocode containing `\1` for the capture group output:

```
cat file | sed -e '/begin/,/end/c\begin\n\1\nend'
```

This should produce

```
a
begin
c
d
end
f
...
```

And I need it to not execute if a match is not found.

I don't know if sed is the right tool for the job, but it may be just 1 step outside of its use case. I'm open to alternatives.

Comment: is every `begin` *guaranteed* to have a matching `end`?  if the answer is 'no', please update the sample with a modified input plus the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be:

```
sed '/begin/,/end/{ /^$/d; }' file
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your edit. After your first response I realized I was asking what I was testing and not what I really needed. Much appreciated.